# Prisma/Axios/NestJS - Error 404 when submitting form

Tags: typescript, axios, nestjs, prisma, solid-js

I'm using SolidJs and NestJS with Prisma to create a Sign Up page but when i submit the form i get the error POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/user/register 404 (Not Found) (This error is also returned by axios).

I'm also using postgresql as database and everything (such as schemas, migrations, etc) seems to be ok.

schema.prisma

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id    Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  email String  @unique 
  username  String?
  password  String?
}
```

Prisma.service.ts

```
import { PrismaClient, User } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export class PrismaService {
  private prisma: PrismaClient;

  constructor() {
    this.prisma = prisma;
  }

  async createUser(data: Omit<User, 'id'>): Promise<User> {
    return this.prisma.user.create({
      data,
    });
  }
}
```

user.controller.ts

```
import { Body, Controller, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaService } from '../prisma.service';

@Controller('user')
export class UserController {
  constructor(private readonly prismaService: PrismaService) {}

  @Post('/register')
  async register(@Body() data: { username:string, email: string, password: string }) {
    const { username, email, password } = data;


    const newUser = await this.prismaService.createUser({ username, email, password });

    return { message: 'User registered successfully', newUser };
  }
}
```

RegisterComponent.jsx

```
import { createSignal } from 'solid-js';
import axios from "axios";

const [username, setUsername] = createSignal('');
const [email, setEmail] = createSignal('');
const [password, setPassword] = createSignal('');

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('/api/user/register', { username, email, password });

    // Handle the response, e.g., show success message or handle errors
    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors
    console.error(error);
  }
};

function RegisterComponent(){
    return(
        <section class="bg-center bg-no-repeat bg-[url('https://media.thegospelcoalition.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/04185025/build-theological-library-1920x1080.jpg')] bg-gray-700 bg-blend-multiply">
        <div class="px-4 mx-auto max-w-screen-xl text-center py-24 lg:py-56">
            <div class="flex flex-col space-y-4 sm:flex-row sm:justify-center sm:space-y-0 sm:space-x-4">
            <div class="flex min-h-full  flex-col justify-center px-6 py-12 lg:px-8">
  <div class="sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-sm">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 22 22" strokeWidth={1.5}  stroke="currentColor" class="mx-auto h-10 w-auto w-6  sm:h-9 h-6 dark:text-white">
  <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M12 6.042A8.967 8.967 0 006 3.75c-1.052 0-2.062.18-3 .512v14.25A8.987 8.987 0 016 18c2.305 0 4.408.867 6 2.292m0-14.25a8.966 8.966 0 016-2.292c1.052 0 2.062.18 3 .512v14.25A8.987 8.987 0 0018 18a8.967 8.967 0 00-6 2.292m0-14.25v14.25" />
</svg>
    <h2 class="mt-10 text-center text-2xl font-bold leading-9 tracking-tight text-white">Crie sua Conta</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="mt-10 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-sm">
    <form class="space-y-6" action="#" onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="POST">
       <div>
        <label for="text" class="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-white">Nome de usuário</label>
        <div class="mt-2">
          <input  value={username()} onInput={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} id="username" name="username" type="text" autocomplete="email" required class="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"></input>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="email" class="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-white">E-mail</label>
        <div class="mt-2">
          <input value={email()} onInput={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} id="email" name="email" type="email" autocomplete="email" required class="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"></input>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
          <label for="password" class="block text-center text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-white">Senha</label>
        <div class="mt-2">
          <input value={password()} onInput={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} id="password" name="password" type="password" autocomplete="current-password" required class="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"> </input>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button type="submit" class="flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-white dark:bg-blue-900 px-3 py-1.5 text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-white shadow-sm focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600">Entrar</button>
      </div>
    </form>

    <p class="mt-10 text-center text-sm text-gray-500">
      Nao possui conta?
      <a href="#" class="font-semibold m-4 leading-6 text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">Crie sua Conta</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
)
}export default RegisterComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

would you recheck URLs?
which one is correct?

- http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/user/register
- http://127.0.0.1:3000/user/register

Comment: Yes, i checked that already. I still get the error even if i change the url